# javascript code blocking me from access to localstorage

Tags: node.js

i am trying to getitem("score") in iframe  in localstorage but there is a js code blocking me from doing that

This is the code that prevents me from accessing localstorage

```
        Object.defineProperty(HTMLIFrameElement.prototype, "contentWindow", {
            get: function() {
                const t = Reflect.apply(e, this, arguments);
                return new Proxy(t, {
                    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(e, t) {
                        if ("localStorage" !== t) return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e, t)
                    },
                    get: function(e, t) {
                        if ("localStorage" === t) return null;
                        const n = e[t];
                        return "function" == typeof n ? n.bind(e) : n
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: you have to create postMessage logic using sender and receiver. https://www.internetkatta.com/programming/cross-domain-sharing-resources-like-login-cookies/

Comment: but i dont own the site its game site and i am tryin to get score with tampermonkey

Comment: then its again cross domain privacy policy. As per HTTP protocol you can't access other domain cookie or localstorage if you dont have access use as sender and reciever.

Comment: Why do you need to use an iframe to access localstorage from tampermonkey at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing `localstorage` or `cookies` of other domain you need to have permission to add sender using `window.postMessage`

As per HTTP protocol you can't access different domain `cookie` and `localstorage` values. Even you can't access data between domain and subdomain also. You need to have access of post file there.

If you can access localstorage if you get access below are step to do :

https://www.internetkatta.com/programming/cross-domain-sharing-resources-like-login-cookies/

**Note** :

Cookies represent an important element of HTTP providing state management to an otherwise stateless protocol. HTTP cookies currently in use are governed by the same origin policy that directs Web browsers to allow cookie sharing only between Web sites in the same DNS domain. As Web applications get richer, data sharing across domain boundaries becomes more important.

https://jisajournal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1869-0238-4-13

Answer (score 0):

The code can be trivially worked around with something like

```
iframe.contentWindow.window.localStorage
//                  ^^^^^^^
```